# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: how to install nvidia drivers for legacy GeForce go 6400 (NV44M)

Tags: 18.04, nvidia

I've searched around, tried the one from Nvidia (NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304-137.run), nothing worked so far for me.

I always used LTS releases and when I did this upgrade from 10.04 I got this issue.

It's an old Sony Vaio laptop. Any alternative to Nvidia is appreciated since so far I can only an ugly square (4:3) screen and can't use the full widescreen resolution.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't an alternative. Either it works with the open-source `nouveau` driver or it doesn't. The old Nvidia driver is incompatible with newer kernels/releases. Try the still supported (until 2012) previous LTS release, 16.04 in a live session.

Comment: * until 2021 for 16.04, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Where to find it? And where to find this nouveau one? In my "Software & Updates", tab "Additional Drivers" I have nothing, empty.  As I said, I got this NVIDIA-Linux-x86-304-137.run from Nvidia official site.
And thanks for your help!

Comment: `nouveau`, the open source alternative for Nvidia graphics is already installed and in use. The current version may or may not work for yours, older version like the one included in 16.04 may work better for older hardware. Again, what you downloaded can't be installed. If that old version was still supported it would appear in Additional Drivers. You never need to install binaries from Nvidia in Ubuntu.